# Работа с циклами C++

Tags: c++, for, вывод

Изучая циклы в с++ наткнулся на интересное задание
Необходимо вывести в консоль такое изображение:

[image: нужно получить такое изображение в консоли]

Основную часть довольно нехитрым способом получилось вывести, а вот с дополнительными "звездочками" возникли проблемы

```
int main()
{ 
int strok,colon;
for(strok = 5; strok >= 1; strok--)
{
 for(colon = 1; colon <= strok; colon++)
     putchar('*');
    putchar('\n');
}
for(strok = 2; strok <= 5; strok++)
 { 
   for(colon = 1; colon <= strok; colon++)
     putchar('*');
    putchar('\n');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int row = 0; row < 9; ++row)
{
    int y = 4 - abs(row-4);
    for(int x = 0; x < 7; ++x)
        putchar(x+y <= 4 || x == y+2 ? '*' : ' ');
    puts("");
}
```

https://ideone.com/XvUVch